# embedded linux can't display more than utf-8 characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, locale, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a beaglebone black with embedded linux. When I plug in an usb-stick that has folders or files with non-UTF-8 characters (like äöü or 学习中文), these characters will not show correctly. I'm using midnight commander to get along with the filesystem.

The `locale` command returns this output:

```
root@beaglebone:~# locale                         
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I have disabled the `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in the local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file to view the non-inherited values.

I can set them by hand if I modify the local `/etc/profile` file and add lines like

```
export LANGUAGE=en-US
# and/or
export LC_CTYPE="en-US.UTF-8"
# ..so on
# but nothing really changes doing this.
```

I tried to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `locale-gen` and ticked the `en_US.UTF-8` also as default. Adding the line `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/environment` changed nothing. Setting `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/rc.conf` and `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/locale.conf` was not very successful because there were no `*.conf` files before (I added them, which is not very intelligent [I know] but who knows).

Installing `language-pack-en-base` like this but didn't work:

```
root@beaglebone:~# apt-get install language-pack-en-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en-base
```

Also tried to `dist-upgrade` my device but (again) no change.

I'm still a linux-noob.

Comment: Does `ls -l` show you everything correct?

Comment: how do you connect to the beaglebone? That will affect terminal capabilities.

Comment: @0andriy now we have modified it to display in the ISO-8859-15 pattern. `ls -l` gives me `öäü` like a question mark in a square and chinese characters like normal question marks.

Comment: @TBR we connect it via ethernet lan-cable and `ssh root@ip`